Krita's setZoomLevel requires division by a strange constant
I want to make a Python script for zooming out in Krita by a constant. I have one that works, but it requires me to do extra division because there is a weird mismatch between zoomLevel and setZoomLevel:
canvas = Krita.instance().activeWindow().activeView().canvas()
zoomLevel = canvas.zoomLevel()
zoomLevel /= 4.166666666666667
canvas.setZoomLevel(zoomLevel/8)

Why does setZoomLevel require this adjustment? Is there a better way to perform the zoom function?
@Andrew Yim Yeah, krita scripts don't require any import statements, here is an example https://scripting.krita.org/lessons/documents
